# Multiple left join where not in another table

Tags: mysql, select

I have the following tables (there is more detailed data in each one, I just put the minimum to create a sample):

```
__________  _____________  _____________  _____________
| person |  | provider  |  | client    |  | user      |
| id     |  | id        |  | id        |  | id        |
| name   |  | person_id |  | person_id |  | person_id |
----------  | name      |  | name      |  | name      |
            -------------  -------------  -------------
```

I'm trying to create a list where I got **all** the *providers* together with all *clients* but **not** the users (only the ones that are providers and/or clients).

I started with this query:

```
SELECT person.id, person.name,
IF(client.id IS NOT NULL, 'Cliente', '') as cliente, 
IF(provider.id IS NOT NULL, 'Fornecedor', '') as fornecedor
FROM person
LEFT JOIN provider ON person.id = provider.person_id
LEFT JOIN client ON person.id = client.person_id
```

But with this I also list users that are not providers nor clients, so I add this part to the code:

```
JOIN user ON person.id = user.person_id 
WHERE user.id IS NULL
```

But now I lost the people that are User + provider/client.

---

BASIC DATA (Mock data)

```
person {
    id: 1,
    name: "test 01";
    id: 2,
    name: "test 02";
    id: 3,
    name: "test 03";
    id: 4,
    name: "test 04";
}
client {
    id: 1,
    person_id: 3
    name: "cli 01";
}
provider {
    id: 1,
    person_id: 3
    name: "prov 01";
    id: 2,
    person_id: 4
    name: "prov 02";
}
user {
    id: 1,
    person_id: 1
    name: "user 01";
    id: 2,
    person_id: 3
    name: "user 02";
}
```

The Data that I want is:

```
person_id: 3 -- it's a client
person_id: 4 -- it's a client and a provider
```

---

How could I list all providers + clients and **not** the users (but show the users that have provider/client)

Comment: I think my title is somehow "wrong" or missing the point, if someone could create a better one, fell free to do so. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show the data you currently get and the data you want to get?

Comment: @Colin'tHart , the Data would be: `person_id: 3 -- it's a client; person_id: 4 -- it's a client and a provider` I added to the question.

Comment: As this is a database question, it would be more handy to have the data in the form of an `INSERT` statement...

Comment: You have an inner join where a (supposedly) primary key column (`user.id`) is null - this does not help in getting any results :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to comment you are not interested in users at all, you just want the person to be client or provider (boolean logic,  so it can be both):

```
WHERE (client.id IS NOT NULL OR provider.id IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: it list only the person_id **2** and **4**. Looking at the mock data, the id **2** is a person (only). not showing **3**

Comment: @MichelAyres so you want person which is at least one of client/provider and not user, but no those which are not anything? Updated the answer.

Comment: @MichelAyres and looking at your data, person.id 3 is a user (with user.id 2)

Comment: There is no problem in showing a user IF he's also a client or a provider

Comment: @MichelAyres I hope I understand now, you do not need the third join at all as it seems, check another edit :)

Comment: Awesome!!! That was silly of me not seeing something so simple! **3** and **4** as results great!